# Yii2 rest api getBodyParams() can't get params from PUT request

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2, put

How can I get "token" param from PUT request?

Controller:

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $params = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();
    return $params;
}
```

Request:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer LL_nACyYVJFJyuHJxcOtiXu3OVNBJ_xo" -F "token=12345" "http://localhost/api/v1/devices/1"
```

Response:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"--------------------------580af3364bd175a7\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name":"\"token\"\r\n\r\n12345\r\n--------------------------580af3364bd175a7--\r\n"}}r
```

I have tried this:

```
return $params['token'];
```

PHP Notice: Undefined index: token

And this

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $params);
```

Will return the same result

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate to some API by passing a token using a PUT request?

Comment: @Jeffrey-Humanized Yes, for every request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is related to the content type of your request.
getting body params from put/post requires `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

try using curl with `-d` instead of `-F`:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer LL_nACyYVJFJyuHJxcOtiXu3OVNBJ_xo" -d "token=12345" "http://localhost/api/v1/devices/1"
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. I just used Postman and it changed Content-type by default in PUT request.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but for those who come accross this again there's another solution. You can keep the Content-Type as application/json if you use AJAX but you need to add json parser to you request component. Here is the doc for it https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start (see Enabling JSON Input section). After that you'll be able to use any params from your request body

Answer (score 0):

You could use Yii's [MultipartFormDataParser](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-multipartformdataparser). This allows you to use `Yii::$app->request->post()` or `Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()` on PUT or DELETE requests, as you know it from POST requests.

You just need to configure it that it gets applied:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'multipart/form-data' => 'yii\web\MultipartFormDataParser'
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

That's it.